# Cannot read property of 'substring' of null from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.
Somehow, I got to the point I get to use the substring in AngularJS.
However, even though I have looked through, I get the message that the 'substring' of null cannot be read.

This is the code:

```
$http.get('../crud/calendars_read_alter.php', {
    cache: true,
    params: {}
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
    angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
        $scope.events.push({
            title: value.Title,
            description: value.Description,
            start: new Date(parseInt(value.StartAt.substring(6))),
            end: new Date(parseInt(value.EndAt.substring(6))),
            allDay : value.IsFullDay
        });
    });
});
```

I thought I input the substring in the correct form, but could anyone please advise me that I might be missing something?

I think this mistake-if so-could help the others as well.

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that either `value.StartAt` or `value.EndAt` is `null` and you are trying to substring null, which won't work.  Check the data being sent to your UI.

Comment: `substring` can be used in angular. that doesn't matter. The problem here is that either your value.StartAt or value.EndAt is null. That's why you can't get the substring.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand why! I guess I also have to check the server side. The data was null. My mistake. Thank you all for correcting! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *||* operator to set default values for properties value.StartAt and value.EndAt (I think they are sometimes null)  so substring is not called on a null value

```
$http.get('../crud/calendars_read_alter.php', {
    cache: true,
    params: {}
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
    angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
        $scope.events.push({
            title: value.Title,
            description: value.Description,
            start: new Date(parseInt((value.StartAt || "").substring(6))),
            end: new Date(parseInt((value.EndAt || "").substring(6))),
            allDay : value.IsFullDay
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Clever fix +1 but I suspect the OP does not even expect such null data, and the real fix might be on the server side.

Comment: Yes, indeed I think it was coming from the server side error. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

`value.StartAt` is null so decide what you want to do with fallback, `new Date()` or just empty string that will give you `NaN`

You can write `start` and `end` as:

```
function getDate(date){
  if(date){
     return new Date(parseInt(date.substring(6)));
   }
   else{
    return new Date(); // or ""
   }
}

start: getDate(value.StartAt),  
end:   getDate(value.EndAt),
```

*Your code snippet*

```
$http.get('../crud/calendars_read_alter.php', {
    cache: true,
    params: {}
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
    angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
        $scope.events.push({
            title: value.Title,
            description: value.Description,
            start: getDate(value.StartAt),  
            end:   getDate(value.EndAt),
            allDay : value.IsFullDay
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you for your support!